# Path photo should not have additional properties yaml file

Tags: rest, yaml, openapi

I am not able to understand what is the problem about this error. I have `PhotoId` parameter defined in components/parameters but it still gives me error. It tells me:

> Structural error at paths./photos
> should NOT have additional properties
> additionalProperty: /{PhotoId}
> Jump to line 126

```
  /photos:
    /{PhotoId}:
      parameters:
        - $ref: "#/components/parameters/XAppBuild"
        - $ref: "#/components/parameters/XAppVersion"
        - $ref: "#/components/parameters/XAppLanguage"
        - $ref: "#/components/parameters/XAppPlatform"
        - $ref: "#/components/parameters/PhotoId"
      get:
        parameters:
          - name: PhotoId
            in: path
            schema:
              - $ref: '#/components/parameters/PhotoId'
```

I tried to define `PhotoId` in components/schema but the error remains the same.

Answer (score 1):

No need to define the `PhotoId` parameter twice

You defined the path incorrectly. It's not clear if you want to have two separate paths of `/photos` and `/photos/{PhotoId}`.

Typically, you would define two unique endpoints to represent both of these with their associated operations.

```yaml
openapi: 3.0.3
info:
  title: stack
  version: "1"
paths:
  "/photos/{PhotoId}":
    parameters:
      - $ref: "#/components/parameters/XAppBuild"
      - $ref: "#/components/parameters/XAppVersion"
      - $ref: "#/components/parameters/XAppLanguage"
      - $ref: "#/components/parameters/XAppPlatform"
      - $ref: "#/components/parameters/PhotoId"
    get:
      responses:
        "200":
          description: OK
          content:
            "application/json":
              schema:
                type: object
    delete:
      responses:
        "204":
          description: 'No Content'
  "/photos":
    parameters:
      - $ref: "#/components/parameters/XAppBuild"
      - $ref: "#/components/parameters/XAppVersion"
      - $ref: "#/components/parameters/XAppLanguage"
      - $ref: "#/components/parameters/XAppPlatform"
    get:
      responses:
        "200":
          description: OK
          content:
            "application/json":
              schema:
                type: object
components:
  parameters:
    XAppBuild:
      name: XAppBuild
      in: header
      schema:
        type: string
    XAppVersion:
      name: XAppVersion
      in: header
      schema:
        type: string
    XAppLanguage:
      name: XAppLanguage
      in: header
      schema:
        type: string
    XAppPlatform:
      name: XAppPlatform
      in: header
      schema:
        type: string
    PhotoId:
      name: PhotoId
      in: path
      required: true
      schema:
        type: string
```